# Differentiate with respect to $x^{a}(t)$

Tags: derivatives, general-relativity

having a little difficulty with this conceptually. Can someone quickly walk through this differentiation please?

$K=\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}\dot{x}^{a}\dot{x}^{b}$

Find $\frac{dK}{dx^{a}}$

In this case, $x^{a}$ is a function of $t$, and the differentiated $x$'s in $K$ are with respect to $t$.

$g_{ab}$ is the metric tensor shouldn't really matter I think.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\frac{\partial K}{\partial x^k}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial g_{ab}}{\partial x^k}\dot{x}^a\dot{x}^b.$$

Comment: But the question requests it be with respect to $x^{a}$?

Comment: but for $\frac{d K}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}(\dot{g}_{ab}\dot{x}^a\dot{x}^b+g_{ab}\ddot{x}^a\dot{x}^b+g_{ab}\dot{x}^a\ddot{x}^b)$

Comment: wouldn't be enough to take $k=a$ for your case?

Comment: $g_{ab}$ is the metric tensor so isn't dependent upon $t$? only on the basis vectors derived from the choice of coordinates

Comment: ok, then $\dot{g}_{ab}=0$

Comment: I got $\frac{d K}{dt}=g_{ab}\dot{x}^a\ddot{x}^b$

Comment: how? where did the half fraction go?

Comment: $g_{ab}\ddot{x}^a\dot{x}^b+g_{ab}\dot{x}^a\ddot{x}^b=g_{ab}\ddot{x}^a\dot{x}^b+g_{ba}\dot{x}^b\ddot{x}^a=2g_{ab}\ddot{x}^a\dot{x}^b$

Comment: Looks like GR work (kinetic energy), are you using the latin letters to mean only the indices 1,2,3?

Comment: Yes, the latin letters run through the indices 1,2,3

Comment: As I thought, however generally the metric is itself a function of the coordinate variables so you can't neglect its derivative